# Join lines that separated by empty lines in Python

Tags: python, string

I want to reformat below text using python:

```
text = """17/05/2013 10:09:15,INFO,xxxxxxxxxx
yyyyyy
zzzzzz

17/05/2013 10:09:15,INFO,xxxxxxxx
yyyyyyy
zzzzzzz"""
```

format them into

```
17/05/2013 10:09:15,INFO,xxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyzzzzzz
17/05/2013 10:09:15,INFO,xxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzz
```

I tried this:

```
def strip(txt):
ret=""
for l in txt.split("\n"):
    if l.strip() in ['\n', '\r\n']:
        ret = ret + "\n"
            else:
            ret = ret + l.strip()
print ret
```

But it turns out, code doesn't recognize the empty line and the result is like this:

```
17/05/2013 10:09:15,INFO,xxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyzzzzzz17/05/2013 
10:09:15,INFO,xxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzz
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: All the `\n` are striped by your `split('\n')`

Comment: Thanks, now I realized where I'm done wrong

Comment: I improved the jamylak's solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> text = """17/05/2013 10:09:15,INFO,xxxxxxxxxx
yyyyyy
zzzzzz

17/05/2013 10:09:15,INFO,xxxxxxxx
yyyyyyy
zzzzzzz"""
>>> print re.sub('\n(?!\n)', '', text)
17/05/2013 10:09:15,INFO,xxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyzzzzzz
17/05/2013 10:09:15,INFO,xxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzz
```

Comment: Give a look to my edit, please, I improved your fine regex pattern to take care of several empty lines.

Answer (score 4):

You can split the text into two as both are separated by two new lines:

```
>>> mylist = text.split('\n\n')
```

Then just print each value, getting rid of the new lines between the bunch of letters:

```
>>> for i in mylist:
...     print i.replace('\n','')
... 
17/05/2013 10:09:15,INFO,xxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyzzzzzz
17/05/2013 10:09:15,INFO,xxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzz
```

Or if you want to store each line in a list, use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [i.replace('\n','') for i in mylist]
['17/05/2013 10:09:15,INFO,xxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyzzzzzz', '17/05/2013 10:09:15,INFO,xxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzz']
```

Comment: A readable one-liner: `[chunk.replace('\n', '') for chunk in text.split('\n\n')]`

Answer (score 1):

I think I might try `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
lines = text.splitlines()
def is_blank(x):
    return bool(x.strip())
print '\n'.join(''.join(v) for b,v in groupby(lines,is_blank) if b)
```

This ends up being insensitive to any number of blank lines between groups which may be desirable.

Answer (score 1):

If you feel comfortable for `regular expressions`:

```
In [5]: import re
In [6]: print re.sub('[^\n]\n', '', text)
17/05/2013 10:09:15,INFO,xxxxxxxxxyyyyyzzzzz
17/05/2013 10:09:15,INFO,xxxxxxxyyyyyyzzzzzzz
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

text = """17/05/2013 10:09:15,INFO,xxxxxxxxxx
yyyyyy
zzzzzz

17/05/2013 10:09:15,INFO,xxxxxxxx
yyyyyyy
zzzzzzz"""

pat = '(\d\d/\d\d/\d{4} \d\d:\d\d:\d\d,INFO,.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)'
regx = re.compile(pat)

print text
print '\n===================\n'
print '\n'.join('%s,%s,%s' % x for x in regx.findall(text))
```

## EDIT

jamylak's solution is better than mine. But the regex pattern can be improved as follows to eliminate successions of several empty lines:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = """17/05/2013 10:09:15,INFO,xxxxxxxxxx
yyyyyy
zzzzzz





17/05/2013 10:09:15,INFO,xxxxxxxx
yyyyyyy
zzzzzzz"""
>>> print re.sub('(?<=\n)\n+(?=\n)|\n(?!\n)', '', text)
17/05/2013 10:09:15,INFO,xxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyzzzzzz
17/05/2013 10:09:15,INFO,xxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzz
```

Comment: -0.  Overly complicated for a simple task. Also, if lines aren't formatted exactly right they silently disappear.

Comment: @Steven You are quite perfectly right. My idea was the following one: 1/ if the OP wrote these lines with this kind of beginning, it is because he doesnt want the treatment to be done for different lines 2/ as soon as the OP will have a code for the treatment of newlines, he will improve himself the regex pattern if he realizes that it is unsufficient (for example by adding ``\s*`` at certain places); because I find tiring to always thinking in place of questioners to all the particuliar cases to which they didn't think themselves.

Comment: @Steven This idea was stupid: based on an assumption (1) and on a non-explicit opinion (2). Moreover, it's right that my solution is heavy. By the way, it is also false because I put commas in the result while the OP doesn't want any. Jamylak's solution is far more light and elegant. It lies on the implicit idea that the OP has a text only composed of the kind of lines he wrote, or if there are other kinds of lines (without beginning with time, I mean) in its text, he is OK for the treatment to concern all the lines anyway. My implicit idea was stupid, and by chance (...continued...)

Comment: @Steven (...continued...) by chance or right implicit idea, the one of Jamylak isn't considered as non fitting. Well the next time, I won't answer to question with not sufficient precision, or I'll try to find a solution as clever as the one of Jamylak. That's life.

Comment: @Steven I thank you for your remark, and your fair un-downvoting. I will upvote 5 of your answers, you'll be able to verify this by seeing the times of this comment and of the votes.

Comment: @Steven As my solution was bad, I improved the regex of jamylak's solution